# splitting the contents in the list in R

Tags: r, regex, strsplit

I have the following content in list

```
"[4]  {PIVOTAL GEMFIRE}                             => {HIBERNATE}                    0.005952381 1.0000000  168.000000 2    \r"
```

and i need to get it as:

```
 4,{PIVOTAL GEMFIRE},{HIBERNATE},0.005952381,1.0000000,168.000000,2
```

and I need to place it rowwise in a dataframe

Comment: Hello and Welcome ! Please explain what you did and what you get (so we can understand your problem and try to help to to fix it). We are not free developing center :P (But I would say to answer to try to use regular expression like `([^\s]+)\s*` ang get the output (something like a list in some languages) and then adding coma to separate values)

Comment: when i tried to use regular expression(when i seperated using space),it is coming like {PIVOTAL and  GEMFIRE}  as two seperate  values but i want it as {PIVOTAL GEMFIRE}

Comment: Rather than explain what you did in words add the exact code to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do (`string` being your string):

```
gsub("((\\S+)|(\\{[^{}]+\\}))\\s", "\\1,", trimws(gsub("[^[:alnum:].{}]+", " ", string)))
```

**Explanation:**

- `gsub("[^[:alnum:].{}]+", " ", string)`: replace everything that is not an alphanumeric character or a curly bracket or a dot (and which can occur multiple times) by a space
- `trimws(...)`: remove the leading and trailing spaces from the modified string you just got
- `gsub("((\\S+)|(\\{[^{}]+\\}))\\s", "\\1",...)`: in the former result, capture everything that is before a space and composed of non spaces or anything in between curly brackets and put a comma after.

Then you can just read in your vector with `read.table`, with `sep=","` to put in a data.frame

**Test:**

```
string <- "[4]  {PIVOTAL GEMFIRE}                             => {HIBERNATE}                    0.005952381 1.0000000  168.000000 2    \r"

read.table(text=gsub("((\\S+)|(\\{[^{}]+\\}))\\s", "\\1,", trimws(gsub("[^[:alnum:].{}]+", " ", string))), sep=",")

#  V1                V2          V3          V4 V5  V6 V7
#1  4 {PIVOTAL GEMFIRE} {HIBERNATE} 0.005952381  1 168  2
```

Comment: what is the purpose of keeping "\\1," is gsub

Comment: @EllantiKishore `\\1` is to put what has been captured (in between brackets in the regex) in the result. So you capture what is before a space that you want to replace with a comma and you put it in the result, followed by a comma.

Answer (score 1):

Replace each `=>`, `[` and `]` with the empty string giving `s1` and then replace any digit or `}` followed by space by that same digit or `}` followed by a comma. Then read it in using commas as the separator.  If comma can appear in the content then use a different separator character.

```
s1 <- gsub("=>|[][]", "", DF$x)
s2 <- gsub("([0-9}]) ", "\\1,", s1)
read.table(text = s2, as.is = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE, sep = ",")[-8]
```

giving:

```
  V1                V2          V3          V4 V5  V6 V7
1  4 {PIVOTAL GEMFIRE} {HIBERNATE} 0.005952381  1 168  2
2  4 {PIVOTAL GEMFIRE} {HIBERNATE} 0.005952381  1 168  2
```

### Note

Test data used:

```
x <- "[4]  {PIVOTAL GEMFIRE}                             => {HIBERNATE}                    0.005952381 1.0000000  168.000000 2    \r"
DF <- data.frame(x = c(x, x), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

**EDIT:** Added missing `}`.